# Total electronic energy as the sum of single particle energies

Tags: density-functional-theory

In Hartree-Fock / Kohn-Sham theory, the total energy of a system of electrons is the sum of single electron energies $\varepsilon_k$ plus some correction $C[\rho]$ depending on the electron density $\rho$, 
$$
E_\mathit{tot} = \sum_{k} \varepsilon_k + C[\rho],
$$
see e.g. the formula at the bottom of this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohn%E2%80%93Sham_equations).

However, it seems in applications the correction $C[\rho]$ is often ignored, see e.g. formula (15) in Stefan Goedecker's *Linear scaling electronic structure methods*. What is the justification for this?

My guesses are:

- The correction is small and can hence be ignored.
- We are mostly interested in energy differences where the correction cancels out.

Comment: 1 year is a long time not to get an answer, maybe copy and paste into https://materials.stackexchange.com?